# What makes these two Controllers related?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm reading a book on AngularJS and There's something that confuses me

There are two Controllers

**EditCtrl**

```
app.controller('EditCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'recipe', 
function($scope, $location, recipe){
    $scope.recipe = recipe;

    $scope.save = function(){
        $scope.recipe.$save(function(recipe){
            $location.path('/view/', + recipe.id);
        });
    };

    $scope.remove = function(){
        delete $scope.recipe;
        $location.path("/");
    };
}]);
```

**IngredientsCtrl**

```
app.controller('IngredientsCtrl', ['$scope',
function($scope){
    $scope.addIngredients = function(){
        var ingredients = $scope.recipe.ingredients;
        ingredients[ingredients.length] = {};
    };

    $scope.removeIngredient = function(index) {
        $scope.recipe.ingredients.slice(index, 1);
    };
}]);
```

What I don't understand is how the `IngredientsCtrl` is a child of `EditCtrl`.  I can't see the relation.  The book clearly states this case, and I'm sure it's the case because the example app works fine, but I need help understanding what it is that makes `IngredientsCtrl` a child of `EditCtrl`.  Doesn't makes sense to me.

**Edit: With relevent HTML**

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="ingredients">Ingredients:</label>
<div class="controls">
  <ul id="ingredients" class="unstyled" ng-controller="IngredientsCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="ingredient in recipe.ingredients">
      <input ng-model="ingredient.amount" class="input-mini">
      <input ng-model="ingredient.amountUnits" class="input-small">
      <input ng-model="ingredient.ingredientName">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-mini" ng-click="removeIngredient($index)"><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> Delete </button>
    </li>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-mini" ng-click="addIngredient()"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> Add </button>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Edit: Snippet from book**

All the other controllers that we saw so far are linked to particular views on the UI. But
the Ingredients Controller is special. It’s a child controller that is used on the edit pages
to encapsulate certain functionality that is not needed at the higher level. The interesting thing to note is that since it is a child controller, it inherits the scope from the parent
controller (the Edit/New controllers in this case). Thus, it has access to the
$scope.recipe from the parent.

**Edit: with routing**

```
var app = angular.module('guthub', 
      ['guthub.directives', 'guthub.services']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', 
    function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.
         when('/', {
             controller: 'ListCtrl', 
             resolve: {
                 recipes: function(MultipleRecipeLoader){
                     return MultipleRecipeLoader();
                 }
             },
             templateUrl: '/view/list.html'
         }).
         when('/edit/:recipeId', {
             controller: 'EditCtrl',
             resolve: {
                 recipe: function(RecipeLoader) {
                     return RecipeLoader();
                 }
             },
             templateUrl: '/view/recipeForm.html'
         }).
         when('/view/:recipeId', {
             controller: 'ViewCtrl',
             resolve: {
                 recipe: function(RecipeLoader) {
                     return RecipeLoader();
                 }
             },
             templateUrl: '/view/viewRecipe.html'
         }).
         when('/new', {
             controller: 'NewCtrl',
             templateUrl: '/view/recipeForm.html'
         }).
         otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two controllers share a Parent-Child relationship if you place the `ng-controller` directive on two nested html elements.

If you take a look at your HTML template, you should see something like this:

```
<!-- parent controller -->
<div ng-controller="EditCtrl">
    <!-- child controller -->
    <div ng-controller="IngredientsCtrl"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understood that from the reading, but in the case of this app, there is no nesting.  The `IngredientsCtrl` stands alone

Comment: Can you share the HTML?

Comment: That looks like `ingredients` template. Check if you have `ng-include` inside the parent template. I mean inside the parent template you should have: `<div ng-include src="'ingredients.html'"` or something..

Comment: There's no 'ng-include` anywhere.

Comment: Well there has to be an element on which `ng-controller="EditCtrl"` is placed.

Comment: I put a snippet of the book where it identifies what I am saying about the child relationship.

Comment: How is that `ingredients` template fetched if not using `ng-include`?

Comment: That's what confused me.

Comment: Does the app use routing..`ng-view`?

Comment: Yes! It does. Is that the reason? I have place the routing code.  So the actual controller javascript code has nothing to do with the inheritance?  That's what I was wondering.  But can you still explain in your answer how the routing affects the inheritance.

Comment: No there isn't. But I think you're right about the routing.  In the `index.html` template there's this `<div ng-view></div>` Thats handles the routing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing in angular as a child controller. However, you can place a controller inside of another in the dom.

```
<div ng-controller="EditCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="IngredientsCtrl">
        // Here you have access to the scope of both controllers
    </div>
</div>
```

The answer to your question "What makes these two controllers related?" is "nothing". They can be nested as I described, but so could any two controllers be.

Both controllers in your example read from the scope. This is bad practice as stated by Miško Hevery himself (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY).

Paraphrasing:

> Inside of a controller you shoul only do write-operations to the scope and in the templates you should do read only

Based on these code snippets. I would not recommend the book you read for learning angularjs.

Comment: Supposedly the book was written by someone who worked on the original Angular development.  I understand what you're saying about the there being no child controller, but the the `IngredientsCtrl` inherits some of the properties of the `EditCtrl`, that's why the author called as being `"created as a child"` of `EditCtrl"`.

Comment: No it does not inherit any properties. When you place it in the dom the way I described you can access variables from both controller. But  the javascript code is basically unrelated.

Comment: Makes sense.  @CodeHater brought to my attention that the the controllers were placed in the DOM through the ng-view. Makes sense now.